# Initialising an object to convert nsdata to uiimage

Tags: swift, initialization, uiimage, nsdata

sorry to ask this question again, im just not understanding it...

converting nsdata to uiimage...

so far-   converted a UIImage to NSData and saved to core data.

tested working by printing the binary saved to console etc.

now i need to convert the binary back to a UI Image and retrive it from core data to display on the image view..

```
//ui image view
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

//initialise imagedata? is this the issue??
var imagedata: UIImage
```

The way im trying to retrieve from core data, works fine for all other items retrieving in core data...

```
do {
        let result = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {


            imagedata = data.value(forKey:"picture") as! NSData
```

this line above shows error: Cannot assign value of type 'NSData' to type 'UIImage'

```
            let image: UIImage = UIImage(data:imagedata as Data,scale:1.0)!
```

this line above shows error: Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage' to type 'Data' in coercion

```
            imageView.image = image
```

also 1 error at class 
Class 'Controller' has no initializers

sorry to ask duplicate question... 
Thanks

Comment: what the problem ?

Comment: sorry, i did edit

Comment: Why do you declare imagedata as UIImage? It should be NSData, right?

Comment: Hi, Yaming Lin, yes i think that was error and changing did fix some issue.  now only 1 issue on line:  let image: UIImage = UIImage(data:imagedata as Data,scale:1.0)! which has error: Cannot convert value of type 'NSData' to type 'Data' in coercion